# Repository Updates Only With Initial Commit

Tags: git, github, git-push

If I run 'git push' in terminal, it won't update my repository on github; however, if I initialize the git, and run the three following: 'git init', 'git add .', and finally, 'git commit -m "Initial commit"', then the repository updates.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Di you commit something new before pushing?

Comment: I'm very new to programming, please bear with me; I've been troubleshooting, while trying to get through Hartl's tutorial; I tried to at first test my parameters while getting picking up where I left off today with the tutorial, so I edited the readme file, and attempted to then run 'git push', however it didn't update on GitHub. So while troubleshooting, I tried 'Git Init', then, 'git add .', and finally, the initial commit.  It updated.  But still, I can't push with the simple 'git push'.

Comment: Also, on a side note (this may help): I reinstalled RVM and Ruby last night mid way through the tutorial.

Comment: and Heroku isn't the app updating either.

Comment: Git push won't do anything if you didn't commit new code... there won't be anything to push. You'll just get an "everything is up to date" message.

Comment: Does that also mean that the time in between the previous push and when you ran the command, that this would just stay the same as well? ie; 17 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it without running `git init`.  That's the command t set up a new repository. Since you already have a clone there isn't anything to create.

Also, you need to actually have some changes to commit. Run a `it status` before running `git add .` to see if you actually have changes to commit.

Comment: I'm more or less trying to understand a lot of why certain codes initiate whichever response from the machine into the application at this point; and again, fairly new to the Ruby On Rails culture and community. In any event- I guess that does make a little sense.  If I don't have anything new to push to the repository I figure it just wouldn't push; however, would that mean that the time difference between each push would not change?  That, and the fact that I did actually revise a line on the README file.  Which I only saw a changed update after I ran the previous three commands to initiate.